# Add checkbox in multiple select box with the CTRL and SHIFT key function also

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selection

I need to implement the multiple select box with the checkbox. But the problem is the functionality to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> down and select a block of values should be retained.

I have achieved the adding checkbox  but selecting the values by holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> keys are not working.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="multSelect">
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="hotels[]" value="1">Value 1</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="hotels[]" value="2">Value 2</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="hotels[]" value="3">Value 3</label>
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="hotels[]" value="4">Value 4</label>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
        multiSelectWithCheckbox();
});

function multiSelectWithCheckbox() {

    jQuery('.multSelect').each(function(){
        var checkboxes = jQuery(this).find("input:checkbox");
        checkboxes.each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr('checked'))
                jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selectColor');

            jQuery(this).click(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).attr('checked'))
                    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('selectColor');
                else
                    jQuery(this).parent().removeClass('selectColor');
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**CSS**

```
.multSelect {
    width:22em;
    height:30em;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    overflow:auto;
}
.multSelect label{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:11px;
}
.selectColor {
    background-color: #3399FF;
}
```

It is working fine. But I need the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> key functionality also. Please give some idea to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.fn.multiSelect = function(o) {
    var defaults = {
        multiselect: true,
        selected: 'selected',
        filter:        ' > *',
        unselectOn:    false,
        keepSelection: true,
        list:            $(this).selector,
        e:                null,
        element:    null,
        start: false,
        stop: false,
        unselecting: false
    }
```

[TRY THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/bMgpc/248/)

Comment: Thank you. It works well. I have done little bit change in the code for my requirement.